# NSPredicate to exclude self from set in self

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios7, nspredicate

I have a `Person` class of `NSManagedObject` type.
This class has `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *mentors;` mentors are many-to-many relationship to `Person` class.

I'm trying to create `NSPredicate`for `NSFetchedResultsController` to exclude `_person` and its `mentors` from results.

```
NSPredicate *prPerson = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != %@ AND NONE mentors = %@",_person,_person];
```

First part of predicate works great, but I have a problems with a second. I also tried `"ANY mentors != %@"` without success.

How to exclude `_person.mentors` from results also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exclude `_person` and `_person.mentors` the following predicate should work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != %@ AND NOT SELF IN %@",
       _person, _person.mentors]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might work:

```
NSPredicate *prPerson = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != %@ AND NOT (SELF IN %@)", _person, _person.mentors];
```

Comment: For some reason I was thinking of `_person.mentors`

Comment: It gives ```terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException```